# Store polymorphic callbacks in Haskell

Tags: haskell, callback, monads, polymorphism

In advance, sorry for this long post.

I'm writing an event-driven application in Haskell, as such I need to store several callback functions for further use. I would like such callbacks to be:

- *enriched* : use of `ReaderT`, `ErrorT`, `StateT` rather than bare `IO`s ;
- *polymorphic* : of type `(MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m, MonadState MyState m, MonadError MyError m) => m ()`, rather than `ReaderT MyContext (StateT MyState (ErrorT MyError IO)))`

Let's forget about the `State` and `Error` layers, for the sake of simplicity.

I started writing a record of all callbacks, stored inside `MyContext`, something like:

```
    data MyContext = MyContext { _callbacks :: Callbacks {- etc -} }

    -- In this example, 2 callbacks only
    data Callbacks = Callbacks {
        _callback1 :: IORef (m ()),
        _callback2 :: IORef (m ())}
```

The main issue is : where to put the typeclasses constraints for `m` ? I tried the following, but none compiled:

- I thought I might parameterize `Callbacks` with `m` such as :

  ```
  data (MonadIO m, MonadReader (MyContext m) m) => Callbacks m = Callbacks {
     _callback1 :: IORef (m ()),
     _callback2 :: IORef (m ())}
  ```

  As `Callbacks` is part of `MyContext`, the latter has to be parameterized as well and it results in an infinite type issue (`MonadReader (MyContext m) m`).
- I then thought of using *existential quantifiers* :

  ```
  data Callbacks = forall m . (MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m) => Callbacks {
     _callback1 :: IORef (m ()),
     _callback2 :: IORef (m ())}
  ```

  It seemed to work fine until I wrote the actual code that registers a new callback in `Callbacks`:

  ```
  register :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m) => m () -> m ()
  register f = do
    (Callbacks { _callback1 = ref1 }) <- asks _callbacks -- Note the necessary use of pattern matching
    liftIO $ modifyIORef ref1 (const f)
  ```

  But I got the following error (simplified here):

  ```
  Could not deduce (m ~ m1)
    from the context (MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m)
      bound by the type signature for
           register :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m) => m () -> m ()
    or from (MonadIO m1, MonadReader MyContext m1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
           Callbacks :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                     (MonadIO m, MonadReader MyContext m) =>
                     IORef (m ())
                     -> IORef (m ())
                     -> Callbacks,
    Expected type: m1 ()
    Actual type: m ()
  ```

  I was unable to find a workaround.

I would be really grateful if someone could enlighten me. What would be *the* good way of designing this, if any ?

Thank you in advance for your comments.

**[EDIT]** As far as I understood ysdx's answer, I tried parameterizing my datatypes with `m` without imposing any typeclass constraint, but then I was unable to make `Callbacks` an instance of `Data.Default`; writing something like this:

```
instance (MonadIO m, MonadReader (MyContext m) m) => Default (Callbacks m) where
  def = Callbacks {
    _callback1 = {- something that makes explicit use of the Reader layer -},
    _callback2 = return ()}
```

... resulted in GHC complaining with:

```
Variable occurs more often in a constraint than in the instance head
  in the constraint: MonadReader (MyContext m) m
```

It suggests using UndecidableInstances, but I heard it was a very bad thing, although I don't know why. Does it mean I have to give up using `Data.Default` ?

Comment: I don't have ghc available right now, but is it because the IORef has a fixed type once constructed? If so, try making an existential newtype over `(MonadIO m, ...) => m ()` and have your callbacks be `IORef <the newtype>` instead.

Comment: Also, is there a reason for using `modifyIORef ref1 (const f)` instead of `writeIORef ref1 f`?

Comment: Polymorphic data is a pretty uncommon need; are you sure you don't just mean _parameterized_ data? If parameterized is enough, then see ysdx's answer; otherwise, let me know and I'll write up a polymorphic version.

Comment: @hzap `writeIORef` makes more sense here, indeed, thank you.

Comment: There are various ways of constructing something like this.  The key question to pick the right way for you is "How will the callback be consumed?".  What code is doing the calling back?

Answer (score 6):

Simple adaptation (make the thing compile):

```
data MyContext m = MyContext { _callbacks :: Callbacks m }

data Callbacks m = Callbacks {
  _callback1 :: IORef (m ()),
  _callback2 :: IORef (m ())}

-- Needs FlexibleContexts:
register :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader (MyContext m) m) => m () -> m ()
register f = do
  (Callbacks { _callback1 = ref1 }) <- asks _callbacks
  liftIO $ modifyIORef ref1 (const f)
```

However -XFlexibleContexts is needed.

Do you really need IORef? Why not using a simple state monad?

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Callbacks m = Callbacks {
  _callback1 :: m (),
  _callback2 :: m ()
  }

-- Create a "new" MonadTransformer layer (specialization of StateT):

class Monad m => MonadCallback m where
  getCallbacks :: m (Callbacks m)
  setCallbacks :: Callbacks m -> m ()

newtype CallbackT m a = CallbackT (StateT (Callbacks (CallbackT m) ) m a)

unwrap (CallbackT x) = x

instance Monad m => Monad (CallbackT m) where
  CallbackT x >>= f = CallbackT (x >>= f')
    where f' x = unwrap $ f x
  return a =  CallbackT $ return a
instance Monad m => MonadCallback (CallbackT m) where
  getCallbacks = CallbackT $ get
  setCallbacks c = CallbackT $ put c
instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (CallbackT m) where
  liftIO m = CallbackT $ liftIO m
instance MonadTrans (CallbackT) where
  lift m = CallbackT $ lift m
-- TODO, add other instances

-- Helpers:

getCallback1 = do
  c <- getCallbacks
  return $ _callback1 c

-- This is you "register" function:
setCallback1 :: (Monad m, MonadCallback m) => m () -> m ()
setCallback1 f = do
  callbacks <- getCallbacks
  setCallbacks $ callbacks { _callback1 = f }   

-- Test:

test :: CallbackT IO ()
test = do
  c <- getCallbacks
  _callback1 c
  _callback2 c

main = runCallbackT test s
  where s = Callbacks { _callback1 = lift $ print "a" (), _callback2 = lift $ print "b" }
```

This code code works even without MonadIO.

Defining "Default" seems to work fine:

```
instance (MonadIO m, MonadCallback m) => Default (Callbacks m) where
def = Callbacks {
  _callback1 = getCallbacks >>= \c -> setCallbacks $ c { _callback2 = _callback1 c },
  _callback2 = return ()}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the infinite type issue: `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type m1 = ReaderT (MyContext m1) IO` as soon as I write `runReaderT (MyContext aCallback) f`...